# SQL Query to find out which Shift produced most diesel engines

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Question: Which shift ('Shiftnumber') produced most diesel vehicles ('engine-type')?

I have the table productionhistory

```
CREATE TABLE productionhistory (
ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Shiftnumber int NOT NULL,
Carid int NOT NULL);
```

and the table vehicle

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle (
ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
`engine-type` varchar(6) NOT NULL);
```

vehicle.ID is the foreign key for productionhistory.carid.

Can somebody help me or give me a clue on how to solve this?

Comment: Your code is not compatible with SQL Server, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to join productionhistory with vehicle to obtain pairs of (Shiftnumber, enginetype).  Now you can simply use WHERE engineType = 'diesel' GROUP BY ... ORDER BY n DESC to obtain the shift in order of most produced engines of that type.

```
SELECT Shiftnumber
     , COUNT(*) AS n
  FROM productionhistory AS ph
  JOIN vehicle AS v
    ON ph.carid = v.id
   AND engineType = 'diesel'
 GROUP BY Shiftnumber
 ORDER BY n DESC
;
```

Comment: There are a few ways to break ties and reduce the result to either one shift or all shifts which match the maximum production value. See: LIMIT, Window functions (like ROW_NUMBER or RANK), etc.

Comment: Thanks! This worked well for me in addition to the LIMIT function.